# Maximal asymptotic in linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, jordan-normal-form

How Can I find maximal asymptotic for $x^{\cdot}=Ax$ where $x\in\mathbb{C}$. I know that A is matrix. But what is algorithm to find that maximal asymptotic in linear differential equation ?

Comment: What is a maximal asymptotic?

Comment: If there exist a real positive function f(t), such that function $\frac{||e^{At}x||}{f(t)}$ is bounded and there exists at least one $x_0$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{||e^{At}x_0||}{f(t)}=1$

Comment: Take $f(t) = e^{\lambda t} $ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with maximal real part.

Comment: @Evgeny Is it possible to use in this case jordan matrix?

Comment: Sure, but for what? You know that $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues and you can choose the one with the maximal real part.

Comment: @Evgeny Yes you are right. I thought about this function $f(t)=t^{p-1}*e^{\mu*t}$ where $\mu$ is maximal real part of $\lambda$ and $p$ is maximal size of Jordan boxes ? If this function correct how can I prove this Fulfilled the first condition ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, then you are right. I always forget about non-simple roots (because they are not typical), so $t^{p-1}$ is really needed here. You can expand any $x$ in Jordan basis; the action of $e^{At}$ on each basis vector is known. And then use the fact tha $\| \sum\limits_{i} v_i \| \leqslant \sum\limits_{i} \| v_i \|$. Also I think that $p$ should correspond to the size of Jordan block for "maximal" eigenvalue.